# Edit masked array including masked entries

Tags: numpy, masked-array

I have a numpy-masked array, where some entries are masked. At some point in my code I want to apply some scaling to the array. I.e. all the values, including the masked ones, have to change according to the operation.

E.g.:

```
a = np.ma.array([1])
a.mask = True
a *= 10
a.mask = False
a
out [1]
```

I want the print result to be 10. But the change is ignored. Is there a simple way to do include the hidden values in the scaling?

Answer (score 0):

The values are stored (or at least accessed via) the `data` property:

```
In [31]: a = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask=[True, False, True])
In [32]: a
Out[32]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 2, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
In [33]: a.data
Out[33]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [34]: a *= 10
In [35]: a
Out[35]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 20, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
In [36]: a.data
Out[36]: array([ 1, 20,  3])
```

But it doesn't let use change `data` directly (though it does let us change `mask`):

```
In [37]: a.data *= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [37] in <module>
    a.data *= 2
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You could set the `mask` to `False`, apply the change, and then restore the mask to the original value.  That may sound round about, but it's probably not any more complicated than what happens under the covers when you use `ma` functions.

I don't use masked arrays much, except to answer questions like this, so don't know its documentation well.

---

`a*b` for a masked array uses `np.ma.multiply(a, b, *args, **kwargs)`.  This is implemented as a instance of :

```
class _MaskedBinaryOperation(_MaskedUFunc):
    """
    Define masked version of binary operations, where invalid
    values are pre-masked.
```

The code's a bit complicated, but it appears to perform the calculation on the full `data` of the masked arrays, and then revert the masked values to those of `a` or `b`.  So in the case of `a*=10`, it is intentionally not changing the masked elements.